# How do I Boot a usb hdd on a iMac?

Tags: live-usb

Boot linux USB hdd to 2006 intel imac. OSX 10.6.8. Mac recognizes the USB HDD but won't boot it. The Linux HDD is Mac compliant.

Comment: Can you boot the Mac from a thumb drive?  Should be the same key combo -- or if you're getting an error message after the Mac tries to load the OS from the external drive, we need you to [edit] that into the question.  You should also take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] -- and welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: You should add more details and context about this problem.  Also, what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: No error messages. I think this is a firmware issue. I have Linux installed on a 2006 MacBook but it will not a USB HDD that has Linux on it. That tells me it's not a Mac OS issue. I suspect their hardware is designed to not allow booting from an external HDD.